# Ultragrid not showing a ValueList for a certain column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ultrawingrid

I have a User Control with an Ultragrid. In a particular form where I add a ValueList. The value list will not show for the particular column I'm interested in. If I then code in another column instead by changing the index value for columns I get the value list in the column.

The code looks like:

```
private void AddCombo(object sender, UcUltraGen.RowClickArgs e)
    {
        ValueList vl;
        if (!ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.ValueLists.Exists("Texas"))
        {
            vl = ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.ValueLists.Add("Texas");
        }
        else
        {
            vl = ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.ValueLists["Texas"];
        }
        var row = e.VariantRow;
        List<PcBase> list = PcBase.PcBaseList.Where(x => x.VariantId == row.Cells["Id"].Text).ToList();
        AddValueList(list, vl);
        ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].ValueList =
            ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.ValueLists["Texas"];
```

And if I change to

```
...
ucUltraGridMain.Grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[2]
```

It works. How can I have changed the behavior of columns[1]?

Answer (score 0):

The property in column[1] was read only that is it only had a "get" implemented. By adding a set it worked. Hope this helps someone.